# Remove the "E" in a number format for very small numbers

Tags: php, mysql

When I echo this:

```
round($number* 100, 12)
```

I get output numbers that look like this:

```
6.6936406E-5
```

How do I remove the "E" and show the numbers as they are, i.e. like this:

```
0.0000066936406
```

Answer (score 2):

use number_format.

```
$number = number_format($number, 12, '.', '');
```

http://php.net/number_format

Comment: $number =$number ."\t"