# Representation of small float numbers in json_encode

Tags: php, json, floating-point, precision

I'm executing the following code in a PHP script:

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->lat = 0.000011399388312455;
echo json_encode($obj) . "\n";
```

The output of the script is

```
{"lat":1.1399388312454999446e-5}
```

As you can see, the number is represented in exponential notation.
Is there some way to represent that particular number in extended notation, in the JSON-serialized object?

The desired output is

```
{"lat":0.000011399388312455}
```

The version of PHP is 5.6.30.

P.S.: This JSON-serialized object will be sent to an external web service that doesn't accept numbers in exponential form. Moreover, it needs to be a number and not a string (`{"lat":"0.000011399388312455"}` won't work).

The number should not be rounded (it's a geographical coordinate).

Here are other similar questions, but they don't fit my case unfortunately.

[php- floating point number shown in exponential form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607819/php-floating-point-number-shown-in-exponential-form)

[Remove the "E" in a number format for very small numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442217/remove-the-e-in-a-number-format-for-very-small-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is implemented in PHP 7.1 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/precise_float_value
As a work around, use other JSON serializers not a default `json_encode`.

E notation is valid form of float representation. In php >7.1 with precision set to -1 results of your code would look like:  `{"lat":1.1399388312455e-5}` which is absolutely the same as `0.000011399388312455` because you have 4 leading zeros.

If you still want to have leading zeroes in json i would go towards strings. They are perfectly fine for coordinates representations.

Comment: Unfortunately passing strings in place of numbers is not an option. An external web service which I'm interacting with could make input validation, marking the body of the request as invalid. However, I agree with you on the equivalence of both representations for the given number. The new implemented options in PHP ( `precision` and `serialize_precision` as linked by you) don't help solving the question.